# Is it safe to delete “inspector” folder from Electron 5 package?

Tags: electron, chromium, electron-builder, electron-packager

I’ve recently updated Electron from v4 to v5 and found a new ~9MB folder in the installed Electron package at **`node_modules/electron/dist/resources/inspector`**. What is this for?

There seems to be no consequences for deleting this folder.

I’m using electron-builder to package my app and it includes this folder in the packaged app.

**Is it safe to delete/exclude it from my packaged app?**

Package used: electron@5.0.6 for 32-bit Windows

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be indeed added by mistake. [It's removed in > 5.0.6](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/19193).

Answer (score 0):

There is no document about this folder but it's deleted at electron@5.0.7.